# How do you get values for settings from a build.sbt file

Tags: scala, sbt, settings

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the values for the settings from my build.sbt file. My sbt file looks like so...

```
name := "projectName"

organization := "com.organization"

version := "0.1.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

...
```

and so on. I need to able to get the value for name and version to use in other files in my application and I don't want to have to hardcode it. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `.value` method for properties and macros magic would do the work. See for example:

```
version := scalaVersion.value
```

**update**: the information above was written under presumption that *project* means `project/*` files that describe the project.

---

If there is need to pass some information from build to the sources then the [buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) sbt plugin may be used. See the project page for usage description.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly but that's not what I'm looking for. I need to know how to get those values in other files in the project.

Comment: All project files are imported to the single namespace. So you can define property in _build.sbt_ and read it in _project/build.scala_

Comment: I don't think your quite understanding what I'm asking for. Say I've got my file in src/main/scala/package1/class.scala, I need to get the version or name or organization etc. from my build.sbt file and use that value in my class